# how to move two lists in opposite direction vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two scrollable lists in my html code and I want both the lists to scroll in opposite direction vertically, that means when I scroll-up one list the other list should scroll-down automatically, for that I am doing something like this but this is not working, kindly help...

```
<script>
            // Add event listener for scrolling
            $("#list1").on("scroll", function () {
            var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#list1").scrollTop()) * -1;
                console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
                $("#list2").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright);
            })

            //Move right column to bottom initially
            $("#list2").scrollTop($("#list2").height());
            //Get actual distance scrolled
            var scrolledright = parseInt($("#list2").scrollTop());
</script>
```

Comment: instead of scrolling the increment amount on the second list, i would calculate the percent the first list is scrolled, then subtract that percent from 100% on the second list and apply it. otherwise the lists would have to be the same length.

Comment: how can I calculate the percent the first list is scrolled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xc286hw1/1/

Basically did exactly what @Dr.AaronDishno suggested in his comment

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

    // Default 2nd list to bottom
    $('#list2').scrollTop($('#list2')[0].scrollHeight);
  
    // Get scrollable height for both lists
    var list1Height = $('#list1')[0].scrollHeight;
    var list2Height = $('#list2')[0].scrollHeight;
  
    // When list 1 is scrolled....
    $('#list1').scroll( function() {
  
      // Calculate current offset % for list1 (being scrolled by user)
      // and new offset % for list2 (scroll position adjusted with this script)
      var list1Offset = ( $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() ) / list1Height;
      var list2Offset = 1 - list1Offset;
      var list2Position = list2Height * list2Offset;
    
      // Set new scroll position for list2
      $('#list2').scrollTop(list2Position);
    });
  
});
```

```css
#list1,
#list2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list1">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>l</li>
    <li>m</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>o</li>
    <li>!</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="list2">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>l</li>
    <li>m</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>o</li>
    <li>!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```